# User name and picture don't show up on new post until page refresh

Tags: reactjs, mern

I have a MERN app that allows logged in user to create posts, with text and images.  When the post is created the component re-renders and the post is adde automatically.  The images and text from the post show up right but the username and user's picture don't show up unless I refresh the page.

This is the posts page:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getTimeLinePosts } from '../../../actions/postAction';
import Post from '../Post/Post.js';
import PulseLoader from 'react-spinners/FadeLoader';

const Posts = ({ user }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { posts, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.postReducer);

  console.log('user ID :', user.user._id);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTimeLinePosts(user.user._id));
  }, [dispatch, user.user._id]);
  return (
    <div className="Posts">
      {loading ? (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <PulseLoader
            color="#485639"
            height={15}
            width={5}
            loading={loading}
          />
        </div>
      ) : posts && posts.length ? (
        posts.map((post, i) => <Post key={i} post={post} index={i} />)
      ) : (
        "You haven't shared anything yet."
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

Here is the individual post component:

```
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Dots, Public } from '../../../svg';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Post = ({ post }) => {
  //const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.authData);

  return (
    <div className="post">
      <div className="post_header">
        <Link to={`/${post?.user.username}`} className="post_header_left">
          <img src={post?.user.picture} alt="" />
          <div className="header_col">
            <div className="post_profile_name">
              {post?.user.first_name} {post?.user?.last_name}
              <div className="updated_p">
                {post.type === 'profilePicture' &&
                  'updated their profile picture'}
                {post.type === 'cover' && 'updated their cover picture'}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="post_profile_privacy_date">
              <Moment fromNow interval={30}>
                {post.createdAt}
              </Moment>
              . <Public color="#828387" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
        <div className="post_header_right hover1">
          <Dots color="#828387" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="post_text">{post.text}</div>
      {post.images && post.images.length && (
        <div
          className={
            post.images.length === 1
              ? 'grid_1'
              : post.images.length === 2
              ? 'grid_2'
              : post.images.length === 3
              ? 'grid_3'
              : post.images.length === 4
              ? 'grid_4'
              : post.images.length >= 5 && 'grid_5'
          }
        >
          {post.images.slice(0, 5).map((image, i) => (
            <img src={image.url} key={i} alt="" className={`img-${i}`} />
          ))}
          {post.images.length > 5 && (
            <div className="more-pics-shadow">+{post.images.length - 5}</div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Here is the postController:

```
exports.getTimelinePosts = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.id;

  try {
    const posts = await Post.find({ user: userId }).populate(
      'user',
      'username first_name last_name picture'
    );

    res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
```

This is the postRequest function:

```
export const getTimeLinePosts = (id, token) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log(id);
  const API_URL = 'api/posts/';
  dispatch({ type: 'RETREIVING_START' });
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(API_URL + `${id}/timeline/`);
    dispatch({ type: 'RETREIVING_SUCCESS', data: data });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: 'RETREIVING_FAIL' });
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Here is the post request part of the postReducer:

```js
case 'RETREIVING_START':
      return { ...state, loading: true, error: false };
case 'RETREIVING_SUCCESS':
  return {
    ...state,
    posts: action.data.reverse(),
    loading: false,
    error: false,
  };
case 'RETREIVING_FAIL':
  return { ...state, loading: false, error: true };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from another user but then his post was deleted and his profile suspended for a few days.  I watied to see if his post would show up, but it has not, so here is the answer.  On the posts.js page in the userEffect, I added post?.length and that fiexd the issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTimeLinePosts(userId));
}, [dispatch, userId, posts?.length]);
```

Now when I create a post the user's name and image show up.

Answer (score 0):

> When the post is created the component re-renders and the post is adde automatically

This is because `posts` are updated and since in your component you are including

```js
const { posts, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.postReducer);
```

this makes the component rerender on every `posts` or `loading` update.

> The images and text from the post show up right but the username and user's picture don't show up unless I refresh the page.

`getTimeLinePosts` will only fire once since it is inside a `useEffect` hook that, according to its dependency array, will only run on the component first mount so that's why when you refresh the page you got the new user info, because with doing so, you are remounting the component so triggering `useEffect`.

one solution is to include `posts.length` to the useEffect dependency array, that will make `useEffect` fire each time the length of `posts` is updated so you no longer have to refresh the page to get the user info.

Answer (score -1):

Do you dispatch anything when the post has been successfully created? It seems as if the user information within the newly created post has not been updated yet when the post timeline loads. So only after you refresh the page, all posts are fetched with all the information included. So maybe you need to wait for the "CREATE_POST_SUCCESS" event (or however you call it), which should be triggered only after the user information has also been added to the new post.

Comment: The post content does get updated right away but not the user information.  I got an answer yesterd and accepted it but now that answer and my commt to the user is gone and his account has been suspended for 5 days.  The answer awas to add posts.length to the useEffect dispatching getTimelinePosts.

Answer (score -1):

did you tried any user data refatech event inside the ON_CREATE_POST_SUCCESS  ? theoritically it should work .